# php mysql query always returns false

Tags: php, android

using the code below, I always get the result false although I have confirmed that the data is in the table.

Is my php wrong somewhere?

```
    <?php
   $con = mysqli_connect(".....", "....", ".....", "Pi");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;  
        $response["name"] = $name;
        $response["age"] = $age;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Tested using the following link: http://joemalloy.co.uk/baj/Login.php?username=j&password=j

[image: Database]

Within my android app the following is used:

Login Request

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://joemalloy.co.uk/baj/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Login Activity

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final TextView tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignIn);

        tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        });

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                // Response received from the server
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("age", age);
                                intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is my php wrong somewhere?` yes, you're not checking returned values

Comment: *"Tested using the following link: `http://joemalloy.co.uk/baj/Login.php?username=j&password=j`"* - and you're using POST arrays. That's a GET method and strangely enough, error reporting wouldn't have even helped here.

Comment: sorry, should have added slightly more content. The calls are coming from within a android app. PHP is not my preferred language, and as such I might end up moving this to a SOAP web service.

Comment: in the PHP part, using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` would have produced notices because `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]` are not defined. (something like: Notice: Undefined index: username in my_script.php on line 2)

Comment: @Jocelyn No it wouldn't and I learned that lesson the hard way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

You do not know whether your query is executing.
Try changing to:

```
if(mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")){....execute query and store results.....}
else{ echo "Error"; }
```

From what I can see, there is a syntax error in this line.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, $username, $password);
```

You need to specify the string types. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
You should change that to

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'ss', $username, $password);
```

Also check your logs, there should be an error or warning for this issue.

Comment: `else{ echo "Error"; }` that won't help them. This will http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use mysqli_error to find out the error message. The point I was trying to make was that you can determine if the query executes or not.

Comment: I understand what you mean.